# Probability of the intersection of many events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables such that $\Pr\{X_i=1\}=1-\Pr\{X_i=0\}=p<1/2$. 
I am interested in finding upper bounds on the probability
$$
\Pr\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}}X_i>\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{2\sqrt{n}}X_i>\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>\frac{1}{2}\right\}=?
$$
Namely it is the intersection of $\sqrt{n}$ events. I am mainly interested in the behavior of the above probability when $n$ is large. Specifically, I would like to understand the exponential decay rate of this probability. Of course simple upper bounds can be obtained by considering only one of the events in the intersection, e.g.,
$$
\Pr\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}}X_i>\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{2\sqrt{n}}X_i>\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>\frac{1}{2}\right\}\leq \Pr\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>\frac{1}{2}\right\},
$$
while the latter can be analyzed using Chernof's inequality, which gives ([tail bounds on Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)):
$$
\Pr\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>\frac{1}{2}\right\}\leq \exp(-nD(0.5||p))
$$
However, I believe that there should be a nice way to handle the intersection, as the above bound is probably quite loose.

When the number of events is fixed (for example, if consider the intersection of two events) then a tight upper bound can be obtained using Chernof's bound. However, I am not sure how to tackle the problem when the number of events grows with $n$, as above.

Comment: If you want something better than just going to $0$, maybe you can make some kind of argument as to why the $\sqrt{n}$ events are close to independent, so that you'd get $(Pr(\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i > \frac{1}{2}))^{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: @mathworker21 how do I make such an argument on the independence? The events seem to be very dependent, aren't they?

Comment: i don't know... $\sqrt{n}$ is a long time. maybe start by trying to show that $S_\sqrt{n}$ is independent from $S_n$. obviously they aren't literally independent, but they should be close to independent